# How to pass value from user input in ArrayList<Integer> ?

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

Basically I'm trying to make a program that calculate student marks by adding carry marks(quizzes, assignments, projects etc) with their final exam mark. The program  will ask the user to enter marks for each quizzes, assignments and so on, which we stored in ArrayList, respectively. The problem is, we didn't get the sum of the elements we stored in ArrayList, instead we get sum =0. Could you help? Thanks.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getQuizMarks(){
    getQuizData();
    return quizMark;
}

public void getQuizData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (JTextField txt : txtField) {
        quizMark.add(Integer.parseInt(txt.getText()));
        Calculate();
    }
}   

   public int sizeArray(ArrayList<Integer> getQuizMarks)
   {    
    return quizMark.size();
   }

public int Calculate(){
    List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        sum += array.get(i);
        }
    return sum;

}
}
```

Comment: You iterate over a brand new empty array. Results are as expected. Your method reads "Create a new empty arraylist. Now grab all of its elements and add them up."

Answer (score 1):

Because you are iterating an empty ArrayList in your Calculate Method.

```
  List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Pass the instance variable to the method where items have been added.

```
public int Calculate(List<Integer> items){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
        sum += items.get(i);
        }
    return sum;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the instance of your arraylist to the calculate method.

Make sure to pass it as a parameter:

```
public int calculate(List<Integer> items) {

}
```

You may be better off using an enhanced for loop instead of a traditional one also.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i : items) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Completing with:

```
public int calculate(List<Integer> items) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i : items) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```